# Async Method Timeout in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, settimeout, cancellation

I am downloading a file and sometimes file size can be big and timeout is not enough. when timeout, I would like to cancel download process because even I get a timeout error, it continues to process the file and give the following exception

> _http_outgoing.js:470
>       throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');    ^
>
> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)

here is my async method

```
router.get('/api/files/GetFile', urlencodedParser, (req, res) => { 

 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {    
    (async function () {
      try {

        var folderName = "File_" + moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY HH_mm_ss');
        await routerFile.CreatePdfZip(req.query.VoucherCodes, req.query.AppNames, folderName);

        var fullzipPath = './FilesToDownload/' + folderName + '.zip';

        zipFolder('./FilesToDownload/' + folderName, './FilesToDownload/' + folderName + '.zip', function (err) {
          if (err) {
            return reject(err);
          } else {

            console.log('zip created');
            rimraf('./FilesToDownload/' + folderName, function () {
              console.log("folder has been deleted");
            });

            fs.readFile(fullzipPath, (err2, zipData) => {
              if (err2) reject(err2);

              const base64 = zipData.toString('base64');
              res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/zip');
              res.type('zip');
              res.end(base64, 'binary');
              console.log('EXCELLENT');
            });
          }
        });       
      } catch (error) {    
        return reject(error);
      }
    })();
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      res.send(error);
   });
});
```

The error occurs in the line *res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/zip');*

PS: router variable comesfrom *const router = express.Router();*

and here is the timeout set

```
const app = express();
app.use(timeout('2s'));
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(haltOnTimedout);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(haltOnTimedout);

function haltOnTimedout(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.timedout)
    next();
  else {
    console.log('TIMEOUT.----------------------------------------------');    
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Or is there better way to set a timeout and cancel the downloading process

PS: CreatePdfZip method takes time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this error, you can check if the `response` is already sent and sent the response only if not sent (But does not really solve/cancel download processing)

```
...
fs.readFile(fullzipPath, (err2, zipData) => {
    if (err2) reject(err2);

    if (!res.headersSent) {
        const base64 = zipData.toString('base64');
        res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/zip');
        res.type('zip');
        res.end(base64, 'binary');
        console.log('EXCELLENT');
    }
});
...
```

[Doc Link](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_headerssent)